# dual boot win 8.1 32bit and 64bit. bootloader issue

Tags: boot, windows-8.1, multi-boot

I installed windows 8.1 x86 on pre installed win 8.1 x64 PC. the new 32 bit OS installed on a different HDD. After i installed it booted to 32 bit os without showing me the OS list(bootLoader). when i use boot option and chose the HDD which have the 64 bit OS it gives an error, but I could repair repair it using a install DVD. Now if change first boot device. I can access to the os i wanted to.

but i need a OS list whenever i boot the machine. Is there any way that i can make a os list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boot the system you have on the first HDD and then, using a Boot Configuration Data (BCD) editing tool, add the system on the second drive to the first drive's boot menu.

To add an additional entry to BCD you can use Windows' built-in `bcdedit.exe` (it is a command-prompt tool, run `bcdedit /?` to get basic usage info) or a GUI-based BCD editor. Once in a similar situation I've used NeoSmart's [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/).

Answer (score 1):

I use bcdedit as @MBu said. and i would like to write here the step i did.

1. Boot from the os which in the primary partition
2. ran cmd as administrator
3. `bcdedit /copy {current} /d "description i wanted to display"` 
   this copied current entry and listed 
   and it gave an ID, and i copied it to the clipboard.
4. `bcdedit /set {ID i copied} device partition = D:` 
   this set device to D because my other os was in the D.
5. `bcdedit /set {ID i copied} osdevice partition = D:` 
   this set osdevice to D because my other os was in the D.

and its worked.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff541231%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#editing_the_boot_menu_in_windows_vista_and_later